# How to remove, modify and extract elements of a list?

Tags: java, list

I'm a Java beginner and I'm currently working on a project that I have almost completed.

I need to remove, modify and extract elements of a list (it's a basic one, though I know there are arrayList(s).) This is driving myself crazy, because I know exactly what I need to do, but I'm not getting what should I need start programming.

```
package lec05;

import java.util.*;

/**
 *
 * @author ulacit
 */
public class Lista {

Celda head;

public Lista() {
    head = null;
}

public void add(Person aPerson) {
    if (head == null) {  // list = empty
        head = new Celda(aPerson);
    } else if (aPerson.getId() < head.getInfo().getId()) {  // add element - left
        Celda aux = new Celda(aPerson);
        aux.setNext(head);
        head = aux;
    } else if (head.getNext() == null) {  // add 1 element - right
        Celda aux = new Celda(aPerson);
        head.setNext(aux);
    } else { // more than 1 - add at the end or in the middle
        Celda actual = head;
        while (actual.getNext() != null
                && actual.getNext().getInfo().getId() < aPerson.getId()) {
            actual = actual.getNext();
        }
        Celda aux = new Celda(aPerson);
        aux.setNext(actual.getNext());
        actual.setNext(aux);
    }
}

public boolean (int id) {
    Celda aux = head;
    while (aux != null && aux.getInfo().getId() < id) {
        aux = aux.getNext();
    }
    return (aux != null && aux.getInfo().getId() == id);
}

public Person restore(int id) {
    Celda aux = head;
    while (aux != null && aux.getInfo().getId() < id) {
        aux = aux.getNext();
    }
    if (aux != null && aux.getInfo().getId() == id) {
        return aux.getInfo();
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}

public void remove(int id) {

}

public void modify(int id, String name) {

}
public Persona extract(int id) {
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    String s = "List{";
    Celda aux = head;
    while (aux != null) {
        s += aux.getInfo() + ", ";
        aux = aux.getNext();
    }
    return s;

}
}
```

Comment: How have you tried solving the problem?

Comment: It looks like you haven't tried anything at all in the methods you need to implement. We're not going to do your homework for you...

Comment: Also... We have no idea what a `Celda` class is.

Comment: @jahroy - but isn't it obvious from the context??  Anyway, Google translate tells me that this is Spanish: "Lista" means List and "Celda" means Cell.

Comment: @StephenC - Yes, it's easy to infer that Celda means Cell.  My point was that we can't see the code that defines his Celda class.  Either way, you're right and your answer is solid.

Answer (score 1):

Hints:

1. You shouldn't implement your own list data structure ... unless you are *specifically required* to do this.  It is better to use an existing `List` type instead; e.g. either `ArrayList` or `LinkedList`.
2. Your code won't compile ...
3. Develop this incrementally:

   - Complete and test the `add(Person)`, `get(id)` and `toString()` methods *before* you try to code the remaining methods.
   - Develop / test the remaining methods one at a time.
4. Implement your own unit tests.  (This is not mandatory, but it will help you test your code systematically.  The unit tests don't need to be beautiful ...)
5. If you are stuck, there are lots of good textbooks on "data structures and algorithms" that explain how a linked list works.
6. What you have is a single linked list; i.e. nodes in the list have links to the next node ... but not the previous node.  The trick for doing operations on a single linked list is that as you are iterating the list you (often) need to keep track of the node that holds the link to the one you are "looking at".  For instance, to remove a node from the list you need to be able to modify the node *before* the current one.

Comment: +1 "_Develop this incrementally... And do them one at a time._"  [That's gold, Jerry!](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j0qm0KUPeD8)

Comment: @jahroy - I've fixed that for you.  Happy?

Comment: @jahroy I expend my day working on this, and I didn't think to put on useless code I created, because as I said it was useless... Before I asked I tried, when I gave up because I didn't have options or because I didn't know what else to do. Do you want me to share my notes? Anyway, thanks Stephen for your help.

Answer (score 1):

It's not difficult at all you can..

You have the head of your `Lista`, what you have is a single linked list

Here is an illustration of a single linked list.
[image: LinkedList]

So when you call for example `remove(int x)`, (assume x is the id of a Celda)

```
Some pseudocode
 aux=Head
 1. Check if you have aux (aux !=null)
 2. Check if the aux has that id
 2.1. if not move to the next Celda and start the same question (aux = aux.getNext()) 
 2.2 if it has, you know what to delete, so you have to have a reference to the previous  Celda of aux if it exist in this method, so know the previous.getNext() = aux.getNext()
```

[image: delete operation]

If you can visualize with images is much easier then to code it ;).

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to add and remove, you need pointers. You keep referencing "getNext" but you don't have a next pointer. Think of a pointer as the connection for each element. If you have 2 elements, how do you know which is first and which is second. You have to have some relation.

Here is a great tutorial to get started: http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/143089-linked-list-tutorial/