# Linked List Recursive removeAll method

Tags: java, recursion, linked-list, singly-linked-list, removeall

I'm trying to define a recursive method that removes all instances in the singly-linked list that are equal to the target value. I defined a remove method and an accompanying removeAux method. How can I change this so that if the head needs to be removed, the head is reassigned as well? Here is what I have so far:

```
public class LinkedList<T extends Comparable<T>> {

private class Node {
    private T data;
    private Node next;

    private Node(T data) {
        this.data = data;
        next = null;
    }
}

private Node head;

public LinkedList() {
    head = null;
}

public void remove(T target) {
    if (head == null) {
        return;
    }

    while (target.compareTo(head.data) == 0) {
        head = head.next;
    }

    removeAux(target, head, null);
}

public void removeAux(T target, Node current, Node previous) {
    if (target.compareTo(current.data) == 0) {
        if (previous == null) {
            head = current.next;
        } else {
            previous.next = current.next;
        }
        current = current.next;
        removeAux(target, current, previous); // previous doesn't change

    } else {
        removeAux(target, current.next, current);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a really bad mismatch of data structure and algorithm.  Lists are _linear_, and there's not much point in using recursion on a list.  If it were a _tree_, then recursion would be appropriate.

Comment: Take a look at my solution if you have the time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I prefer to pass a reference to the previous when you remove to switch previous to the next something like this

```
public void remove(T target){
   removeAux(target,head, null);
}


public void removeAux(T target, Node current, Node previous) {
      //case base
       if(current == null)
               return;

    if (target.compareTo(current.data) == 0) {

        if (previous == null) {
          // is the head
            head = current.next;
        } else {
            //is not the head
            previous.next = current.next;
        }
        current = current.next;
        removeAux(target, current, previous); // previous doesn't change

    } else {
        removeAux(target, current.next, current);
    }
}
```

Check this answer [graphically linked list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17118872/how-to-remove-modify-and-extract-elements-of-a-list/17119115#17119115) may help you to think how to implement it.
If this for training is good but you can do in iterative way.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I changed my method slightly and am now passing in removeAux(target, head, head.next) in my first call to the removeAux method. I tried doing this:    public void removeAux(T target, Node previous, Node current) {
  if (current == null) {
   return;
  } else {
   if (target.compareTo(current.data) == 0) {
    previous.next = current.next;
    current = previous.next;
   }
   removeAux(target, previous, current);
  }
 } but now I'm getting a stack overflow error. Any ideas?

Comment: i don't understand all what you post but in first call you should call actual = head and previous = null ... and in if don't compare to next.. compare to actual

Comment: @user2506781 i edited and post some code, hope it help i did't test may i did some mistake but this is the idead, that is cause you have a single linked list

Comment: Thanks. I tried implementing your method, but I got a nullPointerException. I tried writing a case in remove to check if head is null and if it is equal to target, but that didn't seem to do the trick.

Comment: @user2506781 To do recursion you must have case base , `if (x == null) return;` this is your base case..you don't have to check if `head == null` , post your code i'll try

Comment: @user2506781 i edited, hope it helps. btw here you don't have to use recursion you can do it with a simple loop, but if it is for training it's good

Comment: @user2506781 I did in this way cause i prefer passing the previous but you can do it without, adding a new base case, and for testing it, you always have to test border cases and one middle case :)

Answer (score 0):

You could try to fashion your function so that it works like this.

```
 head = removeAux(target, head); // returns new head
```

A neat trick I learn't from Coursera's Algorithms classes.

The rest of the code is as follows.

```
public void removeAux(T target, Node current) {
  //case base
   if(current == null)
           return null;

   current.next = removeAux(target, current.next);

   return target.compareTo(current.data) == 0? current.next: current; // the actual deleting happens here
}
```